# How to change values in second layout in same Activity?

Tags: android, layout, simpleadapter

My scenario is that I have a activity which shows the cursor stored in SQLite DB. The main layout contains textview at top and a listview. And then I use simplecursoradapter to populate cursor into listadapter and put listadapter into listview. simplecursoradapter use another layout. The problem now is that when I use simplecursoradapter I bring three columns into listview, example: item name, date and price. That is ok if I don't change these values.

Actually I want to add some string to price and form new string such as currency sign. According to my understanding we only can setContentView for one layout not two layouts.
I also tried to populate a new layout and set value but failed

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View textEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist, null);
TextView price = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.price);
price.setText(currency + c.getString(4).toString());

Even there is no problem in syntax and run apps. But when I run the app and check listview, the price still show price only without adding currency sign. I only can add currency sign under the main layout not the second layout used in simplecursoradapter.

In fact, currency is chosen in user preference, and I use sharedpreference to retrieve its value and add to price value in cursor. It seems that simplecursoradapter is using different layout, so cannot do that.

Does anyone has ideas about this case ?

I would be appreciated if methods and codes are provided for similar approach.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question 100%, so this might not be exactly the answer you're looking for.

If you want to have control over how the layout of items look in a list view, you should make your own custom implementation of [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> A ListAdapter that manages a ListView
>   backed by an array of arbitrary
>   objects. (...) To use something other
>   than TextViews for the array display,
>   for instance, ImageViews, or to have
>   some of data besides toString()
>   results fill the views, override
>   getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to
>   return the type of view you want.

If you just google for [custom arrayadapter example](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+arrayadapter+example), you should find enough examples showing you how to implement this. Two such examples are:

- http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
- http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems that your answer is not what I want. May be I try to explain more clearly. I have an activity which contains textview on top and listview is under textview. This is main layout. And then I use simplecursoradapter and populate cursor data into listadapter and put listadapter into listview.The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the data and modify the textview used by simplecursoradapter. 

listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.itemlist,listcursor,new String[]{"item","time","price"},new int[]{R.id.item,R.id.date,R.id.price});

Comment: I want to retrieve the data in "price" in cursor, price is column in cursor. And then add currency sign to price and show in listview. In my listview it contains cursor data. Each record contains item,date and price. But according to my understanding each activity only can "setContentView" for one layout not two.

Does it possible to retrieve the column in cursor used by simplecursoradapter and add string to column and display it in listview but without changing the content of cursor column ?

Comment: For example, one record in cursor in price column is 4000, but I want to add currency sign like "$" to form "$4000", but price column still store 4000 in sqlite DB, only shown as $4000 in listview. Actually itemlist above in simplecursoradapter contains three textviews.

Hope that you understand what I want to do now, thanks !!

Comment: @Tom Cheung: I'm still pretty sure what you're trying to do could easily be done using a custom implementation of an `ArrayAdapter`. I recommend you do a bit of googling and reading on the subject, then you shouldn't have much problem with it. And just as a side-note: if you have clarifications, you should update your original question instead of writing three long comments (to make it easier for others reading your question to get the full picture).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used bindview to solve my problem. In my question I already mentioned that I use simplecursoradapter to get data from SQLiteDB not array. I know arrayadapter works but it doesn't work for SQLite efficiently. Before I extended baseadapter to design my own to add custom views on textviews. It works but too slow if there are lots of data. So simplecursoradapter is more efficient.

I extended simplecursoradapter and override bindview for my own purpose. It works for what I need.

Thanks for your help and link for arrayadapter